# Understanding confusing typedef grammar

Tags: c++, c, typedef, language-lawyer

Consider the following code-snippet

```
typedef int type;
int main()
{
   type *type; // why is it allowed?
   type *k ;// which type?
}
```

I get an error `'k' is not declared in this scope`. The compiler parses `type *k` as multiplication between `type*` and `k`. Isn't this grammar very confusing?

Why is `type *type` allowed by the C++ Standard? Because the grammar says so? Why?

Comment: +1. I think it is a good question.

Comment: It is part of C++ for compatibility with C.  Why it was allowed in C is probably what you really want to know.

Comment: @IronMensan : The grammar is after all derived. Also adding C tag.

Comment: I don't recall the nitty-gritty, but the "namespace" for variables and the "namespace" for typedefs are distinct and separate.  Confusing as hell, if you ask me.

Comment: @HotLicks: That is wrong. There are two identifier spaces, one for user defined types (classes and enum) and one for everything else that includes both variables **and** typedef'ed names. One of main uses of `typedef` in C is actually to create an alias in the global identifier space that refers to an identifier in the user defined type space (i.e. `typedef struct X {} X;` has as sole purpose to define `X` in the global identifier space to refer to `struct X`)

Comment: Like I said, I don't recall the nitty-gritty, and find it pretty confusing.

Comment: good question prasoon saurav...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The question is actually about when exactly a variable name is defined as an identifier, and the language determines that it is right after the point in code where the variable is declared:

```
typedef int type;
int main() {
   type t;   // type refers to ::type
   int       // type still refers to ::type
   type;     // variable declared, this shadows ::type
   type + 1; // type is a variable of type int.
}
```

There are similar rules in other contexts, and it is just a matter of deciding when identifiers are declared. There are other similar situations, for example in the initialization list of a class:

```
struct test {
   int x;          // declare member
   test( int x )   // declare parameter (shadows member)
   : x(            // refers to member (parameter is not legal here)
        x )        // refers to parameter
   {};
};
```

Or in the scope of the identifiers in the definition of member functions:

```
struct test {
   typedef int type;
   type f( type );
};
test::type         // qualification required, the scope of the return type is
                   // at namespace level
test::f(
         type t )  // but the scope of arguments is the class, no qualification
                   // required.
{}
```

As of the rationale for the decision, I cannot tell you but it is consistent and simple.

Comment: Is `int type` (in `main()`) allowed after this : `typedef int type` (at the global namespace)?

Comment: @Nawaz: as long as they are in a different scope there is no problem. `type` outside of `main` will refer to the typedef, `type` in `main` after the variable declaration will shadow the the typedef. It would be utterly confusing if `type type;` was to be allowed but `int type;` wasn't :)

Comment: You commented on @thiton's answer, saying : "*The variable and the typedef'ed name share the same identifier space, the reason it is allowed is because they have different scopes*". What is the exact difference between *identifier space* and *scope*? Does the Standard talk about it?

Comment: @Nawaz: I don't think the standard uses *identifier space* but the rules for name collisions can be colloquially explained that way. Thiton had used "*namespaces for variable/type*", which can be confusing as `namespace` has a different meaning in the language. Given a scope you can have identifiers that refer to user defined types and other user defined *things* (variables, functions, typedef'ed names...). Elements from the first and second group (*identifier space*) can share the name as long as there is a single element in each group with the same name.

Comment: ... `struct T {} T;` declares in a single scope a user defined type `T` and a variable `T` of that type --there is no clash of identifiers. But `struct T {}; enum T { YES };` and `int T; void T();` are both errors as they try to defined a single identifier `T` to mean different things in each one of the sets of names (first case the user defined types, in the second case the general identifier space). Typedef'ed names appear in the second group, so `typedef struct a {} b; void a();` is correct but `typedef struct a {} b; void b();` is an error (`b` in the general identifier space is redefined)

Answer (score 24):

```
type *type; // why is it allowed?
```

C++11 3.3.2/1 says:

> The point of declaration for a name is immediately after its complete declarator (Clause 8) and before its initializer (if any)

So the variable name `type` is not introduced until after the use of the type name `type`; the type name is the only available meaning of `type` during the declarator.

```
type *k ;// which type?
```

The local variable name hides the global type name, so that is chosen here. This is described in C++11 3.3.10/1:

> A name can be hidden by an explicit declaration of that same name in a nested declarative region or derived class.

The fully qualified type name, `::type`, is of course still available.

Comment: @Mike : My question actually was 'what's the rationale behind this rule?'

Comment: @PrasoonSaurav: The rationale for a name's scope to begin after its declaration, rather than at some point before it? I can only speculate about what the language designers were thinking, but that seems more sensible to me than any other option, even if it does allow slightly wonky code like `type *type;`.

Comment: @PrasoonSaurav: Or the rationale for allowing declarations to hide names already declared in outer regions? I'd certainly find it rather restrictive if I couldn't use a name anywhere because someone happened to have declared it in the global namespace.

Answer (score 3):

It is confusing, but this is the only way to get access to `type` variable.
If you want to use `type` type you can do:

```
typedef int type;
int main() {
    type *type;
    ::type *k ;
    return 0;
}
```

Most of those grammar monstrosities come from backward compatibility with C.

Answer (score 1):

The rationale of keeping namespaces (not in the C++ sense, but in variable/type namespace) separate is fairly obvious: When you don't pollute the variable namespace with type names, less code breaks on typedef.

Suppose there was pre-existing code with a variable named "employee". If variables and typedefs lived in the same namespace, a "typedef struct {} employee;" would break the existing code, requiring a change of the variable name (which was more of an issue in pre-IDE days). However, if they do *not* share a namespace, there is no problem and people have one less issue to worry about when choosing type names in large code bases.

Comment: This is unrelated to the question. The variable and the typedef'ed name share the same identifier space, the reason it is allowed is because they have different scopes. Consider the following example: `typedef int type; int type;` which is a compiler error (something along the lines of `type` already defined to be something else).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is allowed probably because it provides flexibility for programmers when choosing name for the variables they declare. In C#, you could declare property of same name as the type:

```
//C# code
class Manager
{
   public Name Name {get;set;}
};
```

When I code in C#, I find this feature very useful. Because I've more options for names to choose from. Otherwise, if I've a type called `Name`, then I wouldn't be able to create a property of the same name, I would be *forced* to choose a different name, say `Name_`, `_Name`, `name`, `NAME` etc - all of which don't appeal to me.

---

As for your code, since in the scope (after declaration of *object* `type`), `type` is already a variable, the *type* `type cannot be referred to directly. But I think this should compile fine and according to the Standard:

```
typedef int type;
int main()
{
   type *type; // why is it allowed?
   ::type *k ;// which type?
}
```

Demo : http://ideone.com/chOov

Comment: @PrasoonSaurav: I know that. But I also tried to answer your question.

Comment: I don't think it adds flexibility but only confusion. :P I knew `::` would make that work but that was not my question after all.

Comment: @PrasoonSaurav: I edited my post, justifying why it is flexible. It is confusing, I agree, but it is flexible too. Confusing and flexibility are not *mutually* exclusive.

Comment: @PrasoonSaurav: Is it the language or your choice of names what adds confusion? I have never been startled by this: before the variable is declared, the identifier cannot refer to it, so it has to refer to whatever that identifier referred to in the previous line. After it is declared, in this scope, it refers to the variable. The rule is quite simple to understand and not really confusing...

Comment: @PrasoonSaurav: Do you find this confusing `int a=10; int main{ int a=99; cout << a; }`. It is confusing only the first time, and then it becomes pretty much clear and obvious.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas : I was initally puzzled by this grammar when I started using C++ long back.  I asked this question to know the rationale behind such rule. That's all. The grammar is quite simple if you understand how actually it is working. For beginners its quite confusing.

Comment: @Nawaz : I find C++ very confusing :P